# how to get string most appears in text file c

Tags: c

how do I get the string that appears most frequently in a text file in c?

I need to create an algorithm that gets a string that has been cited more often in a text file and then writes it, but I have no idea where to start

Comment: You might want to look into Suffix Trees?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stackoverflow. There are many possible answers dependent on your exact requirements, how efficient the solution needs to be, what data structures you have already been taught or can be expected to know, etc. A simple solution would be to have a list that stores unique strings and the count of each string. Then read each string from the file, find it in the list and increment the count, if not found then create a new list entry and set count to 1. It's not a very efficient solution but it's a start and hopefully can lead you to better things.

Comment: It all depends on how you many words you will have and how long they are. There are over 250000 words in the Linux `words` list alone. A *ternary tree* is tailor made for prefix matching and a *ternary tree* that provides a *refcount* would allow you to simply add your words and then traverse the tree to find the maximum *refcount* and you are done. The implementation is non-trivial. Github has such a ternary search tree.

Comment: What do you call a string ? Is it a line from the text file ? Is it a word ? Is it a sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

This code logs most frequently used words, but be aware, it has limitations on the number of words it can process (without crashing,) and number of matches. Also note it does not handle tiebreakers. You can replace "word" with a substring is that's what you are after.
Note: your original request to find "a string" is not useful because "a string" could be the entire string, entire string - 1 character, - 2 characters, etc. You need to resolve what you mean by "a string".
Hopefully, this code gives you a starting point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(void)
{
    char test[] = "This question is too broad for Stackoverflow. There are many possible answers dependent on your exact requirements, how efficient the solution needs to be, what data structures you have already been taught or can be expected to know, etc. A simple solution would be to have a list that stores unique strings and the count of each string. Then read each string from the file, find it in the list and increment the count, if not found then create a new list entry and set count to 1. It's not a very efficient solution but it's a start and hopefully can lead you to better things.";
    char *word[256];
    char most[32];
    int times=0, ndx=0, ix,jx;
    char* cp, *token;
    char* delim = "- . ;,";
    int distribution[256]={0};

    cp = strlwr(test);  // lower case to normalize

    // split text into words
    token = strtok(test, delim); 
    while (token != NULL) { 
        word[ndx] = malloc (strlen(token)+1); 
        strcpy(word[ndx++],token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim); 
    } 

    // count how many times a word is used
    for(ix=0; ix < ndx-1; ix++)
    {
        for(jx=ix+1; jx < ndx;jx++)
            if (strcmp(word[ix], word[jx]) == 0)
                distribution[ix]++;
    }

    // now find the most frequently used word
    for(ix=0; ix < ndx; ix++)
    {
        if (distribution[ix] > times)
        {
            times++;
            strcpy(most,word[ix]);
        }
    }

    printf("most frequently used word was \"%s\", used %d times.\n", most, times);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

most frequently used word was "a", used 4 times.

Comment: Why not simply declare a *pointer-to-array*, e.g. `char (*word)[32];` then  you can have a single `malloc/realloc` and add words as required. (good choice of `32` chars for your word - max word length in the unabridged non-medical dictionary is `29-chars`, so `32` is just right) Only nit above would be the lack of `if (!word[ndx]) { perror ("malloc-word[ndx]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` but as long as you mention that you must always validate EVERY allocation, the omission for brevity is fine.

Comment: I know the limitations of what you are doing is apparent to you and I, but for those just learning C, it may also help if you explain how you provide a fixed number of pointers in an array and then allocate a block of memory to hold each word and assign the starting address of each block to the pointers in sequence. But you do have a good basic approach that will point them in the right direction. Worthy of the UV.

Comment: The question is a about a string, not a word. It could be a substring of the input string where a substring is at least 2 characters. The question is not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, Yes, lots of limitations I touched in the introduction. Maybe I should add a comment at each caveat. chmike, agreed. "a string" if passed in is an easy task. "a string" if meaning any substring which may repeat in the sentence is a more complex undertaking.   My hope was that by seeing how 'word' substrings can be counted, the OP could expand the notion to whatever "a string" means to him.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer a book (PDF free) called **C programming language by Kernighan and Ritchie**, within the first chapter you will find programs regarding the **Word count** that could be your starting point find the count and how they are getting it and then add some code to detect the word which appears the most Good Luck !